# Unable to connect using django-mssql to connect to MS SQL Server 2016 with Django 1.11

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to use django-mssql to connect to MS SQL Server 2016 with Django 1.11 These are my Database settings:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE   = 'sqlserver_ado'
DATABASE_NAME     = 'db'
DATABASE_USER     = 'sa'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '*********'
DATABASE_HOST     = 'localhost'
```

This is the error I get when I try run python manage.py runserver

> (mywork) C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Python Dev\producttimeline>python manage.py runserver
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>    File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>
> File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in 
>       class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in **getitem**
>       conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in **init**
>       super(DatabaseWrapper, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Kaushal_K\Envs\mywork\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in **init**
>       self.client = self.client_class(self)
>
> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       'NoneType' object is not callable
>   ^C

I've looked everywhere and I cannot seem to understand and fix the problem. I hope someone can help! Thanks!

PS:I've already created the database.

Comment: Facing the same issue here connecting to MSSQL 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I used pyodbc instead of mssql and it worked fine.Here is the link how to use pyodbc  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Then looked there - https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql/ - "Django version: 1.8". Tried to install it - and yeah, it works with django-mssql==1.8. Luckily for this particular need I can stay with this old version of Django.

Update. Now the next problem - "ImportError: No module named pythoncom". And "pip install pywin32" also doesn't work.